# How to limit string output length in PHP DOM

Tags: php

I have this code for parsing RSS to HTML.

```
<?php
       $channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
                        ->item(0)
                        ->childNodes
                        ->item(0)
                        ->nodeValue;
```

I want to get only 150 characters from the first description.
How can I limit the length output?

Comment: limit what? `nodeValue`? Add the `xml` url, that would be better to understand.

Comment: What do you mean by "the length output"? Do you mean "the length of the output"? Or something else? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "substr" function of PHP to extract the first 150 characters of any given string.

```
$channel_desc = substr($channel->getElementsByTagName('description') ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,0,150);
```

Refer to *[substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)*.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<?php
// Single-byte strings
$channel_desc = substr($channel_desc, 0, 150);
// Multi-byte strings (UTF-8 support - multi-language support)
$channel_desc = mb_substr($channel_desc, 0, 150);
```

You can use the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) PHP function to trim the string length.  0 is the starting position and 150 is the length.